# iOS 8 search bar in a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

How do I show a search bar in a UIBarButtonItem in iOS 8, like in the clock app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a **Search Bar and Display Controller** next to your **UITableViewController First Responder** in your UI.

Add the ***UISearchBarDelegate*** and ***UISearchDisplayDelegate*** in your code and in your viewDidLoad method add the following code to display the search bar in the navigation bar:

Objective-C:

```
self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
```

Swift:

```
self.searchDisplayController?.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true
```

Then execute the delegate methods:

Objective-C:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

Swift:

```
func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
```

Comment: the searchDisplayController has been depreciated in iOS8

Comment: @IchigoKaL i know that, but i have supported iOS 7 too. 
If you still want to support only iOS 8, i can edit my post.
Or if you want to support most of the devices in the market, just change the Project Deployment Target to iOS 7, and it wont show anymore the Deprecated Warning.

Comment: Oh yea that's true, to support most devices, Thanks!

Comment: how would one make this iOS 8 only compatible